# find volume using double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find by double integration volume of sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ cut off by the plane $z = 0$ and the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ax$.

I proceded like this :

$x = r\cos(\theta)$

$x = r\sin(\theta)$

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $

$V  = \int^ {\pi /2}_0\int^{a\cos(\theta)}_a {(a^2-r^2)}^{1/2}r~drd\theta$

$V  = \int^ {\pi /2}_0[ {(a^2-r^2)}^{3/2}]^{a\cos(\theta)}_a~d\theta$

following the same path and solving the integral further I got certain ans. but it is wrong. I cant find out what is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $r$ is missing a square root.  But that's probably just a typo.  The lower limit of your inside integral should be $0$, not $a$.

But we can't really tell you what you did wrong if you don't post the bit of your work that you think is wrong.

Comment: why the lower limit should be 0 and not a? I thought this for a while earlier

Comment: If the lower limit is $a$ then the lower limit is larger than the upper limit.  $r$ ranges from the origin out to the tangent circle $r=a\cos \theta.$